# Firebase getDoc function not resolving or throwing errors

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm facing an issue with the getDoc function in Firebase Firestore. When I try to use getDoc to retrieve a document from the Firestore database in my web application, it neither resolves nor throws any errors.

Here's my code snippet in js:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.1/firebase-app.js';
import { getFirestore, collection, addDoc, doc, setDoc, getDoc, query, getDocs, onSnapshot, updateDoc, where } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.1/firebase-firestore.js';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "API_KEY",
  authDomain: "AUTH_DOMAIN",
  projectId: "PROJECT_ID",
  storageBucket: "STORAGE_BUCKET",
  messagingSenderId: "MESSAGING_SENDER_ID",
  appId: "APP_ID",
  measurementId: "MEASUREMENT_ID"
};

const app = initializeApp(config);
const db = getFirestore(app);


[... other functions]


async function cropImage() {
    if (!selectedUser) {
        return;
    }

    try {
   
        const imageDataURL = croppedCanvas.toDataURL();
        const cleanedURL = cleanAndValidateUrl(imageDataURL);

        if (!cleanedURL) {
            console.error('Invalid image URL');
            return;
        }
        const userDocRef = doc(db, 'character_sheet', selectedUser);
        const imagesCollectionRef = collection(userDocRef, 'images');         
        
        try {
            const imagesCollectionSnapshot = await getDocs(imagesCollectionRef); //HERE THE CODE STOPS, RETURNING NOTHING
   
            if (!imagesCollectionSnapshot.empty) {
                // If the collection doesn't exist, create it
                await addDoc(imagesCollectionRef, {});
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error retrieving images collection:", error);
        }
        
        // Get a reference to a new document in the images collection
        var newImageRef = doc(imagesCollectionRef);

        // Clean and validate the image URL
        const cleanedImageUrl = cleanAndValidateUrl($('#previewImage').attr('src'));
        if (typeof cleanedImageUrl !== 'string') {
            console.error('Cleaned image URL is not a string:', cleanedImageUrl);
            return;
        }
        
        // Set the document data (image)
        await setDoc(newImageRef, {
            imageUrl: cleanedImageUrl,
            cropData: {
                x: croppedData.x,
                y: croppedData.y,
                width: croppedData.width,
                height: croppedData.height,
                rotate: croppedData.rotate,
                scaleX: croppedData.scaleX,
                scaleY: croppedData.scaleY
            }
        });

        // Display success message
        alert("Image uploaded successfully.");

        // Clear the preview
        $('#previewImage').attr('src', '');
        cropper.destroy();
        console.log('Image uploaded successfully');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error uploading image:', error);
    }
}
```

When I run this code, the error block inside the catch statement is not executed. However, I can confirm that the document exists in the Firestore database, and the Firebase configuration is correct.

Interestingly, when I try to access the same collection and document from another page using getDoc, it works perfectly fine.

Could anyone provide insights into why getDoc might not be resolving or throwing errors in this scenario?

Comment: What gets logged when you add `console.log(imagesCollectionSnapshot.docs.length)` to the line after `const imagesCollectionSnapshot = await getDocs(imagesCollectionRef)`?

Comment: Absolutely nothing! It seems that the code stops working in the const imagesCollectionSnapshot = await getDocs(imagesCollectionRef) line

Comment: Hmm... that's hard to troubleshoot.  Any chance you can reproduce this on a site like stackblitz.com or similar, so that we can have a look?

Comment: if (!imagesCollectionSnapshot.empty) 

Here is it empty or empty() to be used?